# R-prog extraction of contents from xml

Tags: xml, r, data-cleaning

I have used the following code in r to extract contents but there is always an error. Could anyone point out the mistake?

> fileurl="http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens"
>   doc=htmlTreeParse(fileurl,useInternal=TRUE)
>   score=xpathSApply(doc,"//li[@class='score']",xmlValue)
>
> Error:unexpected']' in scores=xpathSApply(doc=doc,path="//li[@class='score']",fun=xmlValue]"

Please help..

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: ToS violation: https://disneytermsofuse.com/english/

Comment: Where do you define `xmlValue`?